# Which to go for: "ne pourrais jamais" or "pourrais jamais"

Tags: négation

> Tes compétences dépassent de loin tout ce que je **ne** pourrais **jamais** espérer accomplir.
>
> vs: Tes compétences dépassent de loin tout ce que je pourrais **jamais** espérer accomplir.

In expressing this idea, I'm wavering between the two. My gut tells me to go for the first, but...

If they are both acceptable, I wonder if the negated version serves to further emphasise her infinite capabilities that could even go beyond my realm of *impossibility*.

---

The way I see it, the rational for using "ne ... jamais" is:

> Devenir président français, c'est ce que je **ne** pourrais **jamais** espérer accomplir.

This is considered to be an already impossibly lofty achievement for me. However:

> Tes compétences te permettent d'aller bien au-delà de **tout ça** {= tout ce que je **ne** pourrais **jamais** espérer accomplir}.

She could achieve things that I **couldn't** even hope to achieve.

Which essentially leads to the first construction.

Answer (score 2):

The basic sentence would be:

> *Tes compétences dépassent de loin tout ce que je pourrais espérer accomplir.*

It is slightly odd as *competences* are not something that can be *accomplies*. You might rephrase it that way:

> *Tes compétences te permettent d'aller bien au-delà de tout ce que je pourrais espérer accomplir.*

Anyway, the core sentence can be strengthened by adding *jamais* (meaning *at any time*, not *never* here).

> *Tes compétences dépassent de loin tout ce que je pourrais jamais espérer accomplir.*

"Your skills exceed by far anything I can ever hope to achieve"

Negating the last part creates a weird sentence, "better than nothing instead of better than anything", and I would recommend avoiding it:

> *Tes compétences dépassent de loin tout ce que je ne pourrais jamais espérer accomplir.*

"Your skills exceed by far anything I can never hope to achieve"

A few notes about ***jamais***:

This word comes from the latin *[**iam**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iam)* and *[**magis**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/magis)* (more) which gave *jam* and *mais* in old French. It is also found in the word *déjà* (already). Like the Latin *iam*, *jamais* has more than one understanding and might mean, "at any time, ever", mostly in the positive sentences (*si jamais je réussis*: if I ever succeed), or "at no time, never" when used alone or in a negative sentence (*Il ne reviendra jamais*: he will never come back).

Comment: Hi. What's your take on the edited part?

Comment: I wouldn't use *jamais* when translating your sentence: "She could achieve things that I couldn't even hope to achieve" : *elle pouvait faire des choses que je ne pouvais même pas imaginer réussir*. With *jamais*, that might be, *elle pouvait faire des choses que je n'aurais jamais réussi, même en rêve...*

Answer (score 0):

- jamais = never
- ne + jamais = never ever

On part de l'origine latine *unquam* (un jour, en un temps quelconque) auquel l'adverbe *ne* va donner le sens négatif *ne unquam* contracté *nunquam*.

*Jamais* est issu de ce *nunquam* latin qui, comme on le voit comporte déjà la négation *ne*. => Nul besoin de la rajouter en français.

"*mes cèdres tenant jamais ce qu'ils promettent.*" (Chateaubriand)

Le *ne* français est une négation dite affaiblie. Cette négation a besoin d'être confirmée par la suite en usant d'un terme portant lui aussi un sens négatif.
D'où la construction *Ne... pas, Ne... jamais...* qui est donc parfaitement correcte.

En conclusion... *jamais* n'a pas besoin d'un *ne* supplémentaire mais *ne*, lui, a besoin de *jamais*. (ou d'un autre terme négatif)

Comment: Tu confonds *ne ... oncques* et *jam ... mais* (cf. esp. *nunca* et *jamás*), peut-être par ce que *oncques* et *jam* ont tous deux un côté « éniantosémique »... ;-)

Comment: Si tu lis l'espagnol: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/11949/what-is-the-difference-if-any-between-nunca-and-jam%C3%A1s

Comment: @jlliagre you speak Spanish, as well ?

Comment: @Aerovistae Cada vez que tengo la oportunidad :-)